# Migrate JSON data from Azure SQL DB to Cosmos DB results in string values

Tags: javascript, azure, azure-sql-database, azure-cosmosdb

I'm trying to migrate data from SQL DB using CosmosDB Data Migration Tool and I successfully migrated data from SQL DB but the result is all values are string

Wondering if there's a way to convert those JSON to Object during migration process?

Here's my sample Query

```
select 
       json_value(Data, '$.timestamp') as timestamp,
       json_query(Data, '$.Product.detail') as [Product.detail],
       json_value(Data, '$.Product.price') as [Product.price]

from myTable
```

nesting seperator: .

Comment: Can you show us your sample data?And what you expect?

Comment: @SteveZhao Sorry for late reply . the output is JSON document in Cosmos db container. Array and Object is double quotes string

Comment: Would you like to use Azure Data Factory? That can achieve this without exporting data from Cosmos db.

Comment: @SteveZhao I'll try. But my concern is my data stored in SQL DB is not normalized. It's a nvarchar type column that stored all JSON data. Is this still available for migration using Azure data factory?

Comment: I have tried this. Data in my SQL DB like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/joJmx.png).And I can get [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7CkZL.png) through Azure Data Factory. I would post  it if you need.

Comment: Yes, Please. I'd like to learn more about Azure Data Factory

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1.create a dataflow and use SQL DB as source.

2.In source option choose `Query`:

SQL:

```
select 
       json_value(Data, '$.timestamp') as timestamp,
       json_query(Data, '$.Product.detail') as [Product.detail],
       json_value(Data, '$.Product.price') as [Product.price]

from test3
```

[image]

3.create a `DerivedColumn`,and change type of column.Expression of `Product`:

```
@(detail=split(replace(replace(replace(byName('Product.detail'),'[',''),']',''),'"',''),','),
        price=toDouble(byName('Product.price')))
```

[image]

4.choose Cosmos DB as sink and mapping like this:

[image]

5.create a pipeline and add the dataflow you created before,then click debug button or add trigger to execute it.
[image]

6.result:

```
{
     "Product": {
        "price": 300.56,
        "detail": [
            "eee",
            "fff"
        ]
    },
    "id": "d9c66062-63ce-4b64-8bbe-95dcbdcad16d",
    "timestamp": 1600329425
}
```

---

**Update:**

You can enable the Data flow debug button, and see the result of expression in Data preview.

[image]

Comment: Step 3 is something like concat in js ?

Comment: Not actually. Step 3 changes String to Array. You can refer to this [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/data-flow-expression-functions).

Comment: Sorry, But I don't see any new doc in Cosmos DB after published dataflow without any error. Did I miss something?

Comment: Maybe  you didn't execute it. I update my answer and you can see the step 5.

Comment: Thanks. It's working!

By the way, is there playground website or some tools that can let us test the expressions (Step 3)?

Comment: You can directly test the expression in Azure Data Factory. See my update.

Answer (score 1):

One option is to export your SQL data to a plain CSV file, do any reformatting with your favorite tool, and import the cleaned CSV or JSON file using the Cosmos migration tool.

With PowerShell, for example, the process could be:

1. Export SQL data to CSV
2. Use PowerShell [Import-CSV](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/import-csv?view=powershell-7) to read the data as an array of custom objects
3. Use PowerShell to modify the custom objects in memory to convert types, reformat, validate, etc
4. Export the cleaned data back to CSV or JSON using [Export-CSV](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/export-csv?view=powershell-7) or [ConvertTo-Json](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/convertto-json?view=powershell-7)
5. Import the cleaned file using Cosmos Data Migration Tool

Comment: Does extra exporting gain fees ?

Comment: Importing to Cosmos will use your provisioned throughput. Not sure on SQL export.